# In React get SyntaxError : Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs

I am a beginner in react

in this code create class component and use useState but not working

i can't fount what i missing

Please help.

[image]

```js
class ModuleDialog extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //this.state = {open: false};
  };

  //const [open, setOpen] = useState({false});
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  handleClickOpen = () => {
    //setOpen(true);
    this.state = {open: true};
  };
  handleClose = () => {
    //setOpen(false);
    this.state = {open: false};
  };
  
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
      ......
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Its not valid Javascript syntax, also, you can't use hooks in class component, hooks are valid only in function components.

Comment: @DennisVash how to use useState in class compponent ?

which is the best way to manage useState in class component?

Comment: Check out React docs

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify those 2 functions - and aggregate to 1 function.

Also hooks - require functional components instead class.

```js
const ModuleDialog = () => {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);

  handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };
  
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div>
      <p><button onClick = {() => handleClick()}</p>
      {open ? <p>true</p> : <p>false</p>}
    </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can we use useState in class component ?

Comment: not recommended - https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html
i suggest just transform to functional component